# How to change Camera size not a qrboxsize with html5-qrcode.min.js

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

I could not  change the camera width and height but not a size of qrboxsize, also would like to know how to avoid click button "request camera permission", when user go into the page it ask for camera permission and after that set rear camera automatically

```
<body>
<script src="Scripts/html5-qrcode.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .result {
        background-color: green;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .row {
        display: flex;
    }
</style>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 10%" id="reader"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="padding: 30px;">
        <h4>SCAN RESULT</h4>
        <div id="result">Result Here</div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<span class="result">' + qrCodeMessage + '</span>';
    }

    function onScanError(errorMessage) {
        //handle scan error
    }
    
    let qrboxFunction = function (viewfinderWidth, viewfinderHeight) {
        let minEdgePercentage = 1; // 70%
        let minEdgeSize = Math.min(viewfinderWidth, viewfinderHeight);
        let qrboxSize = Math.floor(minEdgeSize * minEdgePercentage);
        return {
            width: qrboxSize,
            height: qrboxSize
        };
    }

    let html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
        "reader",
        { fps: 30, qrbox: qrboxFunction },
/* verbose= */ false);
    html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);


    
</script>
```